# Get Python process's own PID when starting

Tags: python

I'm creating a desktop application manager program in Python. It's a GUI program made with `tkinter`. I get a list of running applications by this command:

```
subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Format-List Id,Name,Path"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It runs automatically when the program starts but it doesn't show the python process that runs it. Whenever I refresh the application list by running that command manually afterwards the Python process shows up also.

Basically the code I run is this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Format-List Id,Name,Path"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        for line in io(p.stdout, encoding='utf-8').readlines():
            line = " ".join(line.split())
            print(line)

root = tk.Tk()
gui = Gui()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm not keen to make automatic refreshing because it's quite heavy and makes the program less responsive. Is there some way to run the refresh function after the mainloop is called to get the Python process's PID listed as well?

Comment: Your command contains condition `Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle }` which means that only processes with non-empty main window titles are found. If your Python app doesn't create a window at the moment when `refresh` method is called than it makes sense that you can't get process ID. You can change your powershell command to search only Python processes: `Get-Process | where -Value "python" -CIn ProcessName | Format-List Id,Name,Path`

Comment: The problem was just what I thought it was. I just didn't quite know how that powershell command actually worked. Now it works perfectly. Thank you for your answer.